# How to reset a CancellationToken properly?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have been playing round with the `Async CTP` this morning and have a simple program with a `button` and a `label`. Click the `button` and it starts updating the `label`, stop the `button` it stops writing to the `label`. However, I'm not sure how to reset the `CancellationTokenSource` so that I can restart the process.

My code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button.Content = "Start";
    }

    async Task DoWork(CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            label.Content = i++.ToString();
            await TaskEx.Delay(50, cancelToken);
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (button.Content == "Start")
        {
            button.Content = "Stop";
            DoWork(cts.Token);
        }
        else
        {
            button.Content = "Start";
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You need to recreate the `CancellationTokenSource` - there is no way to "reset" this once you set it.

This could be as simple as:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (button.Content == "Start")
    {
        button.Content = "Stop";
        cts.Dispose(); // Clean up old token source....
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // "Reset" the cancellation token source...
        DoWork(cts.Token);
    }
    else
    {
        button.Content = "Start";
        cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: When are you supposed to dispose of it on close of the application? As you have to wait before the Thread is done, else you get ObjectDisposed exception.

Comment: @user2587718 It really depends on what type of object, etc.  I'd recommend asking your own question regarding this.

Comment: Should really do a null check before disposing but this was good since it is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Trying to learn abit more about CancellationTokens, Why are you not disposing of the cts straight after the `Cancel` call? Should it only be disposed of the next time it is about to be newed up?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and I figured it out that the best way to solve it is to create cancellation token source newly just before calling the method.

this is what I do on my start button click:

```
cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
Task.Factory.StartNew(StartUpload, cancellationToken);
```

I change the caption for the same button to cancel and when a click occurs on cancel, I call

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

Here is the full code:

```
if (button3.Text != "&Start Upload")
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}
else
{
    try
    {
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(StartUpload, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var v in ex.InnerExceptions)
            builder.Append("\r\n" + v.InnerException);
        MessageBox.Show("There was an exception:\r\n" + builder.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Now, with .NET 6 you can use `TryReset()` method which `Attempts to reset the CancellationTokenSource to be used for an unrelated operation.` see [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48492/) issue and [CancellationTokenSource.cs](https://github.com/stephentoub/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs) for more details.